# list particular extensions in directory format in PHP

Tags: php

Hi I am trying list all the html and XML formats in a particular directory using Php.

I tried the following: I succeeded with only showing html but couldn't include XML with this.

Can some help me with this:

Here is what I have tried: How do I add .xml to the below filter.

```
<?php
include("lock.php");

$myDirectory = opendir(".");


while ($entryName = readdir($myDirectory))
{
   if ($entryName != "." && strtolower(substr($entryName, strrpos($entryName, '.') + 1)) == 'html')
    {
      $dirArray[] = $entryName;
    }
}


closedir($myDirectory);


$indexCount = count($dirArray);
Print ("$indexCount files<br>\n");

sort($dirArray);

print("<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 class=whitelinks>\n");
print("<TR><TH>S.No</TH><TH>Filename</TH></TR>\n"); 

for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
        if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != ".")
{ 
        print("<TR><td>");
        print($index + 1);
        print("</td>");
        print("<TD><a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a></td>");
        print("</TR>\n");
    }
}
print("</TABLE>\n");
?>
```

Comment: What did you try and did it work?

Comment: I added the || and && with html. didn't work. So looking for different logic here? I am totally new to php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easy, use glob

> Find pathnames matching a pattern
>   you can treat it as an array

```
$dirArray = glob("*.{html,HTML,xml,XML}",GLOB_BRACE);

$indexCount = count($dirArray);
Print ("$indexCount files<br>\n");
print("<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 class=whitelinks>\n");
print("<TR><TH>S.No</TH><TH>Filename</TH></TR>\n"); 

for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
        if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != ".")
{ 
        print("<TR><td>");
        print($index + 1);
        print("</td>");
        print("<TD><a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a></td>");
        print("</TR>\n");
    }
}
print("</TABLE>\n");
```

This solution takes care of lowercase uppercase file extensions pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

```
$count = 0;

foreach (glob("*.xml") as $file) {
    echo $file;  //the file name
    $count++;
}

echo $count;
```

By doing so, you can just replace the `.xml` to `.pdf` or any file extensions you're looking for. The `$count` variable will store the amount of files with the specified extension.

Comment: Sorry! I am totally new to PHP but how do I get glob inserted to my code above.

Comment: By adding on your first ẁhile`loop, the instruction I've writen in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to check for any characters at the end of a string.

```
while ($entryName = readdir($myDirectory))
{
   if (preg_match(/'^.+\.(html|xml)$/', $entryName))
    {
      $dirArray[] = $entryName;
    }
}
```

A cleaner solution would be to use [pathinfo()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

```
while ($entryName = readdir($myDirectory))
{
    $fileParts = fileinfo($entryName);
    if(in_array($fileParts['extension'], ['html', 'xml']))
    {
        $dirArray[] = $entryName;
    }
}
```